# Render Component Presentation cd_dynamic 7.1.0 error: cannot access Page

Tags: java, content-delivery, dynamic

I've got a compilation error with the following lines:

```
JSPPage dcdPage = new JSPPage(pageContext, pageId);
ComponentPresentationAssembler cpAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(dcdPage);
```

**error: cannot access Page**

Any help? We were using before the cd_dynamic-2013.jar without any problems.

Comment: This isn't DXA, is it?

Comment: I changed the tag, I wanted to add the java one, by the way is related with the update of libs from 2013 to 7.1.0, wher ecan we find which are the main differences between both versions?

Comment: Checking it again it's related with the installation of dxa-web-application-java. As with the new dependencies there's no cd_wai package, that it's the one that contains the Page class.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. We needed to add the cd_wai-2013 lib